# Re-add edge loops after using ctrl f

Tags: modeling, edges

I am working on a really big project and I made an error in my mesh so I had to remove the faces and used <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to add a new one back but it ends up like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can use something like <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to add a few new loops in that one face? It does not need to be aligned with the old one, I just need to add something in there.

Comment: Ctrl F opens the faces menu. Did you mean F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Delete the extra faces so the hole is even
2. Select the boundary with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>*> Grid fill*. If it looks strange, adjust the options in the redo panel until it looks right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you it worked :) it even made it look like it used to